# React Native and React Navigation — How to get screen title to show in header and bottom tab navigator to also show

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am teaching myself React Native and building a fairly simple app,[`irMobile`](https://github.com/davesag/irMobile).

I've set up each screen with (using the About screen as an example)

```
static navigationOptions = () => ({
  title: 'About'
})
```

and in my app's main component

```
const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({ About })
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({ MainNavigator })
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(StackNavigator)
```

then in the component itself

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <AppContainer />
      </View>
    )
  }
```

My screens render with a nice nav bar at the bottom but I don't get any titles in the header, just an empty space.

I've gone through [the docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html) several times looking to see what I have missed and I'm stumped.

If I use the inspector in the iOS simulator I can select the header and it shows it to be a `View` at `x: 0, y: 44` with `width: 375` and `height: 43.7`, so the thing is there I just can't see it.

I've tried setting a `headerStyle` to `{ backgroundColor: 'red' }` to see if I can at least see that, but no.

[image: screen snap of iPhone simulator showing header]

However, if I change the `StackNavigator` to put the `About` screen in there along with the `MainNavigator` as follows:

```
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({ About, MainNavigator })
```

Then I get my header showing up as expected, but the bottom tab bar no longer shows.

[image: screensnap of iPhone showing header but missing tab navigator]

So that's confusing.

The docs are a bit vague on how to get both a header and a bottom tab navigator into the same app.  Clearly, being a bit of a React Native noob here, I am missing something really obvious and simple.

What am I failing to understand and how do I fix this?

Source code at [github.com/davesag/irMobile](https://github.com/davesag/irMobile).

Answer (score 5):

By setting `navigationOptions` inside the component, you apply it to the navigation element that is calling the component.

So in your case, the title you define in `About` applies to the bottom tab, and not to the screen as you would like to.

Rather than setting `navigationOptions` as a static property inside the component, you need to define it directly when creating the stack navigation.

In addition to this, I think you want to nest the stack inside the bottom tab navigation, not the other way around. By doing so, you can have a different title for each screen.

Here is an example:

```js
const AboutStack = createStackNavigator({ About: { screen: About, navigationOptions: { title: 'About Title' } } });
const CreditStack = createStackNavigator({ Credit: { screen: Credit, navigationOptions: { title: 'Credit Title' } } });

const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  About: { screen: AboutStack, navigationOptions: { title: 'About Label' } },
  Credit: { screen: CreditStack, navigationOptions: { title: 'Credit Label' } },
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

Like this, the header title will be "About Title" and the tab label "About Label".

Answer (score 2):

Okay I have worked it out.

The trick is to use [`getActiveChildNavigationOptions`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html#getactivechildnavigationoptions).

So now my code looks like

```js
const navBar = useStorybook({ Balances, Settings, About })
const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(navBar, {
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation, screenProps }) =>
    getActiveChildNavigationOptions(navigation, screenProps)
})
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({ MainNavigator })
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(StackNavigator)
```

As @Remeus pointed out, the titles in my actual screen components were only making it to the `MainNavigator` and not accessible by the `StackNavigator`.

Rather than invert my stack however and create a StackNavigator for each tab, it seems to me to be cleaner to leverage `getActiveChildNavigationOptions` to grab the screen components' `title` (and other) `navigationOptions`.

This works perfectly.